# Swift restore original image color after casting a tint

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an image, inside a `UIImageView`, that comes with a default color, let's say a custom grey. 
In my code at some point I set a different `tint` in this way

```
myImageView.image = myImageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
myImageView.tintColor = someCondition() ? UIColor.red : UIColor.lightGray
```

The fact is that I am not able to get back to the image's original grey color. My question is if there is a way to substitute the `UIColor.lightGray` part of my code with something telling the `UIImageView` **not** to use any tint, but its original color.

Comment: Have you tried *UIColor.clear* or *nil*?

Comment: yep, but the both make the image transparent unfortunately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To not apply any tint you can set the image rendering mode like this:

```
image.renderingMode = .alwaysOriginal
```

In your code you could say:

```
let renderingMode: UIImageRenderingMode = condition ? .alwaysTemplate : .alwaysOriginal
myImageView.image = myImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(renderingMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach to change/remove tint on tap

```
    var imageView:UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.image = someImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    img.tintColor = .cyan
    return img
}()
```

Add gesture recognizer to image view or button with action and then just assign image that is already assigned to image view but with different rendering mode

```
@objc func imgTap(){
   imageView.image! = imageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
}
```